# What is the role of Source Index Register in the below code?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, x86-16, cpu-registers, emu8086

I was going through some assembly code involving general purpose registers in 8086 microprocessor, I found the below code.

```
mov SI,2000h
mov [2000h],230d
mov [2002h],25d   

mov ax,[2000h]
mov bx,[2002h]

add ax,bx 
mov [SI],ax
```

I need help knowing what SI is doing in the last step. Also is it a proper addressing way?

Comment: The value 2000h was put in SI in the first line. `mov [SI], ax` would move the 16-bit value in AX to the memory offset stored in SI. So it would move the 16-bit value in AX to memory offset 2000h. Yes it is a valid addressing mode. I won't fill in all the blanks because I have seen these questions in comp sci assignments

Comment: In the first line, is it the value or the address (2000h) that is being stored in SI?

Comment: The value 2000h is being store in SI, and is later used as if it is an address.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks for the help @MichaelPetch.